# How do i convert a PDO object to a string in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I would like to change the results of the query

```
$PDOSelectTeam = $db->prepare('SELECT team FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE :userNameToLookUp'); 
$PDOSelectTeam->bindParam(':userNameToLookUp', $username); 
$PDOSelectTeam->execute();
```

from a PDO object to a string in order to use strcmp($pdoResult, "somestring"). How would I do this? 
(I am comparing the pdo to a string in order to verify which team the user belongs on which can be "8514", "10526", or "ALL")
Current Output:

`Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string`

Comment: can you please update your question by putting what **output** you are getting...so that we can have better idea.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave done! :)

Comment: have you tried **fetching** your data first? my guess $pdoResult is the result of the query execution and you missed that vital step. $pdoResult is just a resource pointing to the results from which you have to read first.

Comment: may be its not object error you passed $username not in string format..

Comment: if there a reason why you want to compare an PDO Object to some string? what string are you possibly even thinking of comparing to it?

Comment: @Caleb - [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) is a handy thing to know about.

Comment: @Caleb Can you tell us why you want Compare PDO object with another object. Because converting PDO object to string & compare then with another String don't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @Memor-X i added the reason to the question

Comment: @mi6crazyheart i hope my edit helps clear that up

Comment: @Caleb : For knowing which team a user belong to, is it really a Single solution for you to compare whole PDO Object to a specific string?  Can't fig. out any other simpler method. Because comparing whole PDO Object with another string is not a good idea.

Comment: @mi6crazyheart do you know of any other solutions? If you could mark them as an answer that would be helpful. The whole PHP code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275717/why-wont-php-redirect-when-pulling-a-variable-from-a-database

Comment: @Caleb : I saw that post. Tell me once are you using any kind of NUMERIC flag for different kind Team ? Ex: 100=TeamA, 200=TeamB ? If that, then it's you just need to extract TEAM column value by PDO & compare that SPECIFIC TEAM COL value with your predefined value to know in which category the user belong to.

Comment: @Caleb You can follow the answer given by ```Pamblam``` at the bottom. That exactly you should do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first result of a query:

```
$result = $PDOSelectTeam->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now, `$result` contains as associative array of the first returned row.

```
strcmp($result['team'], [string])
```

If you're expecting more than one result you can loop them like so..

```
while($result = $PDOSelectTeam->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        strcmp($result['team'], [string])
}
```

See: [PDO::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)